# Retrieve ListPreference inside PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, listpreference, preferencescreen

How do I retrieve a ListPreference inside my PreferenceScreen?

I have tried with the following, and they both throws null exception.

findPreference(key) 
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(key)

```
private void loadLayout(int appWidgetId) {
SharedPreferences.Editor shared_config = prefs.edit();
Layout layout = db_adapter.fetchLayout(appWidgetId);

...

ListPreference widget_text_color = (ListPreference) findPreference("widget_text_color");
widget_text_color.setValue(String.valueOf(layout.getTextColor()));

...
shared_config.commit();
```

}

```
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Layout/Output">
    ...
    <ListPreference
        android:key="widget_text_color"
        android:title="Text color"
        android:summary="Choose text color"
        android:entries="@array/colors"
        android:entryValues="@array/colors_rgb"
        android:dialogTitle="Choose a color" />
    ...
</PreferenceCategory>
```

> 03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.feral.widget/com.feral.widget.Prefs}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at com.feral.widget.Prefs.loadLayout(Prefs.java:234)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at com.feral.widget.Prefs.loadPreference(Prefs.java:267)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at com.feral.widget.Prefs.onCreate(Prefs.java:77)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   03-15 17:50:42.250: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(441):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)

Comment: Show your code, along with the exception.

Comment: Added function, and exception

Comment: ListPreference widget_text_color = (ListPreference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("widget_text_color"); =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)` in your onCreate of the PreferenceActivity?

Comment: I was calling loadLayout() before addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences) in onCreate. My bad, thank you